# Laptop display stays dark with proper driver and resolution

Tags: boot, graphics-card

I have a XMG Clevo P150HM Laptop with a ATI Radeon HD 6970 M Graphics Card and a Full HD Display. When I boot it, the BIOS screen is there, then there is the Windows logo and after that the round thingy spinning, but when there should be the login screen the display goes dark and stays that way.

Further investigation revealed something funny: Reinstalling Windows 10 runs without any problem. But when Windows is installing updates and drivers, as soon as the ATI driver is installed, the display goes dark and stays that way. I've tried two times, the second time I installed drivers downloaded from the ATI website rather than the drivers through the Windows update mechanism. The moment the ATI drivers are installed the problem occurs. This is a rather new developement, I've been using this laptop for quite a while and it did work well.

Then I wanted to install linux, but I didn't get that far: after the BIOS and the grub screen the display goes dark and stays that way. Apparently after the grub screen the boot process switches to another resolution, probably the native display resolution, which seems to trigger the problem. The linux distributions I've tried are Ubuntu 18.04 and CentOS 8.1, booted from a USB stick.

Lastly I connected the laptop via HDMI to my TV. During the Windows boot process there was a 'No signal' text on the TV. But the moment the laptop display went dark there was a reaction on the TV: The 'No signal' text disappeared and there was an input indicator 'HDMI 1920x1080'. Apart from that the TV display stayed dark as well. Once I disconnected the HDMI cable from the laptop the 'No signal' text reappeared.

My guess is that there is something physically broken with the graphics card. My question is, what exactly might that be? Has anybody experienced something similar and investigated further? Is there a reasonable chance that I can fix this?